# Experiment: More aggressive review queue indicator

Tags: discussion

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, I announced [an experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/1438) that would:

- Turn on the review queue indicator whenever there's a task available in any queue.
- All queues with at least one task will be marked with a red dot. There are no grey dots:

  [image: Inbox Zero indicator]

**This *will* mean you'll be notified of outstanding tasks you can't clear.** We are aware of a problem that people will be notified of queues that they don't have the privilege to access. That's next on the list to fix. The goal is to be more aggressive with the indicator to see if we can clear tasks more quickly. Please let us know if we've gone too far.

And in general, we're interested in any feedback to this change: positive, negative or noncommittal.

Answer (score 3):

We have a low volume of review tasks on this site. Today there was one post in "Low Quality Posts" and "Late Answers", but the review queue indicator did not show as red.

This screenshot is from later in the day; the "Late Answers" queue has a red dot and has a post to review, but the main queue indicator has no red dot. I think this was actually a First Post too, but that red dot was also not present.

[image: missing queue indicator]

Comment: For me, I came on and there was one review task for a new post, and I did get a red indicator. Possibly a caching issue for you? Not sure, but when I heard of this from the CM team, I asked for our site to be added to the experiment. This should help alert users that there are actually items in the queue, which can be forgotten on lower traffic sites.

Comment: Most likely you cleared the notification and were waiting for the one hour grace period between notifications to expire. (See: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly))

Comment: @JonEricson I see the same behavior on first use of the day with Chromium 63.0.3239.108: items in review queues but no red indicator for main review queue icon.

Answer (score 2):

I keep getting a red mark but when I look, there is nothing for me to review …

[image]

This is *very annoying* because the system is pestering you into look at the tab yet there is nothing for you to do. The aggressiveness becomes nagging and build up resentment: why should I waste time clicking on it when most of the time, there is nothing for me to do?…

Comment: I have also seen this behavior today.

Comment: I think what happened is that you did a Close Votes task, but the task hadn't been cleared when you came back an hour or more later. This is a problem we are considering correcting, but it might not be possible without causing performance problems.

Comment: @JonEricson If your system cannot tell me that there is nothing for me to review, then there is no point in making it more aggressive. It just adds noise. ☹